# How to implement all types of APIs request in Flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, api, rest, flutter-getx, state-management

I want to implement all the type of HTTP request in a API using Flutter GetX state management.

I have managed to do the "get" request.

I want to implement all the type of HTTP request in a API using Flutter GetX state management.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this [document](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/index#getconnect) by Getx , in which you can find how to implement the API methods with Getx.